# React leer JSON externo y mostrar info

Tags: json, reactjs, map

estoy teniendo problemas para leer este JSON y colocar los datos en la vista.

```
{"datosOferta":{"nombreOferta":"2.0TD Plan Online (0-10kW)","nombreComercializadora":"IBERDROLA CLIENTES, S.A.U.","r2":null},"datosGeneralesPrimerAnio":[{"cabecera":"Total estimado electricidad","valor":614.27,"texto":null},{"cabecera":"IVA","valor":30.71,"texto":null},{"cabecera":"Total primer año","valor":644.98,"texto":null}],"datosGeneralesSegundoAnio":[{"cabecera":"Total estimado electricidad","valor":644.42,"texto":null},{"cabecera":"IVA","valor":32.22,"texto":null},{"cabecera":"Total segundo año","valor":676.64,"texto":null}],"datosElectricidadPrimerAnio":[{"cabecera":"Término fijo","valor":13.4,"texto":null},{"cabecera":"Término de potencia","valor":114.75,"texto":null},{"cabecera":"Descuento Anual fijo","valor":30.0,"texto":null},{"cabecera":"Consumo electricidad","valor":503.39,"texto":null},{"cabecera":"Impuesto sobre electricidad 0,5%","valor":3.01,"texto":null},{"cabecera":"Equipo de medida","valor":9.72,"texto":null}],"datosElectricidadSegundoAnio":[{"cabecera":"Término fijo","valor":13.4,"texto":null},{"cabecera":"Término de potencia","valor":114.75,"texto":null},{"cabecera":"Consumo electricidad","valor":503.39,"texto":null},{"cabecera":"Impuesto sobre electricidad 0,5%","valor":3.16,"texto":null},{"cabecera":"Equipo de medida","valor":9.72,"texto":null}],"datosGasPrimerAnio":null,"datosGasSegundoAnio":null,"caracteristicas":{"caracteristicas":"Precio antes de impuestos: \nTermino Potencia Punta: 30,667470 €/kW año;\nTermino Potencia Valle: 4,104338€/kW año;\nTermino Energia:0,167797 €/kWh.\n\nEstos precios no incluyen el coste del mecanismo de ajuste (Real Decreto-ley 10/2022)\nFinanciación bono social cuota fija: 0,03671762 €/día\nLos precios de los términos de potencia y energía no varían durante 12 meses. Se ofrece a nuevos clientes un descuento de 30€ por contratación online.\nNo requiere contratar servicios adicionales. No requiere servicios adicionales.\n","infoAdicional":"Servicios Gratuitos: Servicio de Asistencia Hogar Iberdrola (Servicio de asistencia y reparaciones hogar 24hrs y Servicio de orientación jurídica), y Factura Electrónica.\n\n","peaje":"4","consumoMinimoGas":null,"consumoMaximoGas":null,"consumoMinimoElectricidad":0,"consumoMaximoElectricidad":999999,"potenciaMinimaElectricidad":0,"potenciaMaximaElectricidad":10,"periodoValidez":"Oferta válida desde 15-nov-2022 hasta 30-nov-2022","limitaciones":"Válido para clientes domésticos, pequeños negocios y comunidades de propietarios.","condicionesPenalizacion":"No se aplican condiciones de permanencia","penalizacionMaxElec":null,"penalizacionMaxGas":null,"ofertaTel":false,"ofertaInternet":true,"ofertaOficina":false,"facturacion":"E","periocidadRevisionPrecios":"Anual","condicionesRevisionPrecios":"Precios vigentes durante 12 meses, sin perjuicio de las actualizaciones que se puedan producir, por la variación del IPC, por las variaciones a la baja o al alza en las tarifas de acceso y por los conceptos regulados que puedan ser aprobados por las Administraciones para su aplicación durante la duración del contrato.\n","componentesRegulados":true,"atencionCliente":"IBERDROLA CLIENTES, S.A.U.$900 225 235$clientes@iberdrola.es$https://www.iberdrola.es/","webOferta":"https://www.iberdrola.es/luz/plan-online","webContrato":"https://www.iberdrola.es/webclipb/gc/prod/es_ES/planes/docs/cg-planes-ibercli-12-2021-es.pdf","serviciosObligatorios":null,"serviciosNoObligatorios":null,"impuestoHidrocarburos":null,"impuestoSobreElectricidad":"0,5","impuestoElectricidad":"5","impuestoGas":"5","impuestoGeneral":"21"}}
```

tengo el siguiente código

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
class App extends React.Component {
   
    // Constructor 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
   
        this.state = {
            items: {},
            DataisLoaded: false
        };
    }
   
    // ComponentDidMount is used to
    // execute the code 
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(
"aquilaurl.com/api")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) => {
                this.setState({
                    items: json,
                    DataisLoaded: true
                });
            })
    }
    render() {
        const { DataisLoaded, items } = this.state;
        if (!DataisLoaded) return <div>
            <h1> Pleses wait some time.... </h1> </div> ;
   
        return (
        <div className = "App">
            <h1> Fetch data from an api in react </h1>  {
                items.datosOferta.map((item) => ( 
                <ol key = { item.id } >
                    User_Name: { item.nombreOferta}
                    </ol>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    );
}
}
   
export default App;
```

El error que me tira es el siguiente: TypeError: items.datosOferta.map is not a function

Yo necesito mostrar, nombreOferta,nombreComercializadora, y dentro de datosGeneralesSegundoAnio el campo valor que en este caso es: valor":644.42"

Answer (score 0):

El JSON que has puesto es un objeto y no un array. Es decir, tienes un mapa clave => valor, y no una lista de mapas. Si la API te devolviera un array, sí podrías iterar con `.map`.

```
{
    "ofertas": [
        {
            "nombreOferta": "Plan Online",
            "nombreComercializadora": "Iberdrola",
            "datosGeneralesPrimerAnio": { /*loquesea*/ }
            /* Más datos */
        },
        {
            "nombreOferta": "Plan Español",
            "nombreComercializadora": "Stack Overflow",
            "datosGeneralesPrimerAnio": { /*loquesea*/ }
            /* Más datos */
        },
        /* Más ofertas */
    ]
}
```

Ahí si podrías desde el código llamar a `items.ofertas.map(oferta => <Loquesea />)`.

Comment: Hola, bien eso entendido, pero como hago para leer ese que tengo porque no puedo cambiarlo no tengo acceso es un api externa.

Comment: Con el json que dejas de ejemplo puedes acceder a nombreOferta sin hacer map y solo agregar items.datosOferta.nombreOferta y también items.datosOferta.nombreComercializadora directamente ya que no es un array